# SLD2 - Fastest method to draw multiple instances of one texture

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I would like to draw multiple instances (like 100000) of the same texture at the same time (rotatable and on different positions).
Currently I'm using `SDL_RenderCopyEx` (using a shared `SDL_Texture*` for that) and I'm wondering if I'm using the correct function for that purpose. Is there a faster way, as I'm down at 18 FPS. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i remember SDL2 doesn´t provide any function to make instanced rendering, so you have to iterate through your objects and draw them 1 by one (and thats why are your FPS falling down)

Also i don´t understand why did u add an opengl tag here, but when we talk about opengl, i recommend you checking instanced rendering http://learnopengl.com/#!Advanced-OpenGL/Instancing

Comment: Thanks for the great link, opengl is also an option, if SDL is not supporting it...

Comment: I expected mixing opengl and SDL is easy. But it isn't. I will removed the opengl tag

Comment: It is not recommended to mix SDL_Renderer and OpenGL rendering, but you can use these libraries together without problem, SDL for input,sound,window management and OpenGL for rendering.